# Can't find /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, kali-linux, virtualbox, cd-command

For some reason, every time I need to go to passwd or even shadow, It does not allow me.

For example:

```
cd /etc/passwd
```

Output: `cd: not a directory: /etc/passwd`

Same thing with shadow. Because of this, I can not find my users and their passwords. Does anyone have solutions? I am not sure if I accidentally deleted the directory with rmdir or not but I doubt.

Also, I deleted all the files in my virtual box and it was still not there when I started up a fresh one. Do I need to download another .ova for it???

Also, it was **Kali linux** for the Virtualbox I was using

Comment: I am so stupid, I for got to use cat at the start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `cd`.  This allows you to change to a directory.  `/etc/passwd` is not a directory.

You can see that with:

```bsh
$ file /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd: ASCII text
$ ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3281 Feb  9 06:43 /etc/passwd
```

Note that the first character on the `ls` response is a `-`.  If `/etc/passwd` were a directory it would be a `d`.

Instead, you'll want to use something other than `cd` to read the file.  This could be `cat /etc/passwd` to read it, or `sudo vipw` to open it in an editor for editing.

The same thing exists for `/etc/shadow`, except it typically contains password hashes, so it is not world-readable.  You'll need `sudo cat /etc/shadow` to read it, and `sudo vipw -s` to edit it.